# How to minimize current commands with oneliner or smth much shorter?

Tags: vim

well, to get the appropriate view of vim windows (check the image) i should type such commands:

1. vim foo.txt
2. :bel ter (to get the terminal window below vim .txt file)
3. Ctrl-W-W (to switch from terminal back to the .txt file)
4. :resize +30 (to make the .txt file view +30 lines from below)

The question is: how to minimize current commands with oneliner or smth much shorter?

Thanks for your attention.[image]

Comment: to get the appropriate view you should add the string from @YuriKhristich answer to your .vimrc file and then use `\t`shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **steps 2-4** can be performed via `leader`+`key` shortcut. Try this:

`nmap <leader>t :bel ter<cr><c-W><c-W>:resize +30<cr>`

My `leader` is backslash, so my shortcut will be: `\t` in this case.

As for the **step 1** - what do you mean? Do you want to start a new empty file with the name 'foo.txt'? It could be done this way:

`nmap <leader>t :e foo.txt<cr>:bel ter<cr><c-W><c-W>:resize +30<cr>`

Comment: this is great! thanks a lot!
to answer your question: i do not want to start a new file, just avoid this switching between windows.

Comment: I hope it's obvious now how you can make your own shortcuts with a `leader`. Just type the chain of your commands with `<cr>` (that means `Enter`) at the ends.